# UTL_FILE.get_line returns extra byte ORACLE

Tags: oracle

I need check the header of a .csv file using UTL_FILE

I need to compare the header line with a value from the database.

```
UTL_FILE.get_line(file_handle, buffer);
```

eg.

```
 dbms_output.put_line( length(buffer_db)); 20
 dbms_output.put_line( length(buffer)); 21
```

the length of the varchar from the csv is one byte longer than the value from the db.  I've tried trimming it, does nothing, there are no white spaces on the ends.

If I force the max line size it works.

eg.

```
UTL_FILE.get_line(file_handle, buffer, 20);
```

Since I have to check for multiple different headers, i cant exactly do that.

I just cant seem to figure out where this extra byte is coming from on the retrieved line.

Comment: You can [`dump`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/functions055.htm) the values to see how they differ; useful if there's no obvious difference. I'd guess there's a linefeed character - e.g. if the file was created in Windows. Speculation though clearly. If there is then you can strip it with `replace`; a simple `trim` wouldn't have been looking for whatever character you have.

Comment: Im not a big oracle guy, how would I dump the values to see the difference.  I have printed them, there is no visible difference and for sure no leading or trailing spaces, whatever is there is masked.

Comment: This actually worked like a charm:

Comment: regexp_replace(column_name,'[^[:print:]]')   //replaces all non printable characters.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [the `dump()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/functions055.htm) to display the numeric representation of each character in the string, in decimal or hex, so you can see non-printable characters:

```
select dump(<some string>) from dual;
```

You can't call `dump` directly inside a `dbms_output` call - it can only be used in SQL statement (PLS-00204) - but you can assign it to another variable and then display that:

```
declare
    ...
    buffer_dump varchar2(4000);
begin
    ...
    utl_file.get_line(file_handle, buffer);
    select dump(buffer) into buffer_dump from dual;
    dbms_output.put_line(buffer_dump);
    ...
```

Since you're dealing with a CSV file it might be reasonable to guess that it has Windows-style line terminators (CRLF), and the `get_line()` is including the carriage return in the result, which would be indicated by the extra character at the end being represented by `13` (in decimal ASCII).

```
declare
    buffer varchar2(4000);
    buffer_dump varchar2(4000);
begin
    buffer := 'Field1,Field2^M'; -- terminated with \r
    select dump(buffer) into buffer_dump from dual;
    dbms_output.put_line(buffer_dump);
end;
/

Typ=1 Len=14: 70,105,101,108,100,49,44,70,105,101,108,100,50,13
```

If that is the case you can remove it with [`replace(<string>, chr(13), '')`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/functions153.htm), or [`trim(trailing chr(13) from <string>`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/functions219.htm), or - as you found yourself - a regex.

```
...
    buffer := trim(trailing chr(13) from buffer);
    select dump(buffer) into buffer_dump from dual;
    dbms_output.put_line(buffer_dump);
...

Typ=1 Len=13: 70,105,101,108,100,49,44,70,105,101,108,100,50
```